# Como identificar se uma requisição utiliza HTTPS?

Tags: php, https

Tenho que identificar se o sistema que está nos enviando uma requisição é HTTPS.

```
if ($isHTTPS){
  #faça alguma coisa
}
else{
 #faça outracoisa
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Da seguinte forma:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') { //HTTPS }
```

Comment: Funciona, mas possui algumas ressalvas. Uma discussão sobre pode ser encontrada no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/